# ¿Qué está mal? Ingreso dos listas y las comparo si hay un elemento igual en ambas debe imprimir True y sino False

Tags: python

```
lista1=[0]
lista2=[0]
cuantos=0
x=0

cuantos=int(input("Inserte cuántos números tendrá su lista:"))

while cuantos>=1:
    for x in range(cuantos):
        lista1.append(input("Lista 1:"))

    for x in range(cuantos):
        lista2.append(input("Lista 2:"))

    for x in range(cuantos):
        if lista1[x]== lista2:
            print("True")
        else:
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, cuando inicializas una lista aquí:

```
lista1=[0]
lista2=[0]
```

Ya estás agregando un elemento a cada lista que es el 0, una lista en python si la quieres vacía se escribe así:

```
lista1=[]
lista2=[]
```

Ahora, cuando quieres saber si un elemento está en una lista, se usa el operador "in".

Ejemplo:

```
lista1=[1,2,3,4,5]
if 5 in lista1:
    print("El 5 esta en la lista1")
else:
    print("El 5 no esta en la lista1")
```

Ahora tu código rescrito con lo mencionado anteriormente quedaría así:

```
lista1=[]
lista2=[]
cuantos=0
x=0

cuantos=int(input("Inserte cuántos números tendrá su lista:"))

while cuantos>=1:
    for x in range(cuantos):
        lista1.append(input("Lista 1:"))

    for x in range(cuantos):
        lista2.append(input("Lista 2:"))

    for x in range(cuantos):
        if lista1[x] in lista2:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```

Nota: Una cosa más, como la inicialización de las listas esta fuera del while, entonces en cada ciclo se seguirán agregando elementos pero no se vaciará.

Espero esto haya resuelto tus dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que no te hace falta el `for` para comprobar si existe o no. Lo puedes hacer utilizando `in` y te ahorras codigo innecesario.

Le hice unas modificaciones a tu código así que ahora quedaría así

```
lista1=[0]
lista2=[0]
cuantos=0
x=0

cuantos=int(input("Inserte cuántos números tendrá su lista:"))

while cuantos>=1:

    for x in range(cuantos):
        lista1.append(input("Lista 1:"))

    for x in range(cuantos):
        lista2.append(input("Lista 2:"))

    #Aqui va el cambio, utilizamos "in" en vez de "=="
    if lista1[x] in lista2:
        print("True")
    else:
      print("False")
```

Espero que te haya servido. 
Saludos✌ y cualquier duda dímelo.